# How to initiate ethereum transaction in HD wallets using python?

Tags: pyethereum, web3.py, hd-wallets

I've managed to generate HD wallet for ethereum where I have Master Key, xpriv, xpub (156 in lengh) keys but for signing a transaction I need private key of address(64 Characters).

How could we generate a private key from the xpriv?

Or how to initiate a transaction with xpriv?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/michailbrynard/ethereum-bip44-python?

Comment: Yes. I've tried it but it is also generating xPriv key. Is it possible to make a transaction using the extended private key in python?